# sticky bootstrap footer overlapping content of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.0, I have sticky footer placed at bottom of my page.Footer is overlapping content of page in phone and tablet view.

footer code is written below:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#footer 
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#push
{
    height: 60px;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
}
/* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    }
```

basic page Skeleton:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
.....
</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
......
</div>
</div> <!-- End -Wrap -->
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
            ....
      </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me what kind of changes i need to do i my code.

Comment: A sticky footer by default is supposed to overlap content. So are you just trying hide the sticky footer on tablet/mobile views?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html it want overlap content

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no need of using wrapper. The latest version of the [sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) that can be found in the [official examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples-custom) are not using and it works nicely.

Here is the CSS

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

For the below HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Read a ton of answers that were half baked but this as the saying goes, "just worked." Two thumbs up~!

Comment: but the footer needs to be responsive so its height needs to change = setting a fixed height is a *non-responsive* solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your nav bar and container in the div having wrap id and not footer

Dummy Structure:

```
 <div id="wrap">
   <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>  // say ur nav bar code 
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"> my body  </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><%--wrap ends here--%>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
```

Stickyfooter.css

```
/* Styles go here */

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
 }

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
 }
.container .credit {
   margin: 20px 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem in css, but i have given height in some **DIV**, so it was not working.

eg. With Bug

```
<div style="height:400px">
</div>
```

I have removed height -

```
<div>
...
</div>
```

Thank you all for answering...